# How can I add 2 words in var word =

Tags: javascript

I've got this script:

```
function validateform() {
  var textarea = document.getElementById('textareabox');
  var word = '<?php echo $answerbutton_of_this_page; ?>'; 

  var textValue = textarea.value.toLowerCase();
  if (textValue.indexOf(word) != -1) {
    document.getElementById("correcto").innerHTML = '<?php echo $outputvali_of_this_page; ?>';
    return true;
  } else {
    document.getElementById("incorrecto").innerHTML = 'Incorrect!  The term is not recognized as the name of a cmdlet, function, script file, or operable program.';
  }
}
```

It worked great, until I got pages that have more than 1 answer. 
I've been trying to modify the script to accept 2 or more answers, but I cannot get it to work...

I added another var word with an extra esle: if {} else {} else {}
I been googling for answers, but I can't find anything. 
Could someone send a link that could help me out?

EDIT: 
I solved it by adding this:

```
function validateform() {
  var textarea = document.getElementById('textareabox');
  var word = <?php echo json_encode($answerbutton_of_this_page); ?>;
  var word2 = <?php echo json_encode($answerbutton2_of_this_page); ?>;

  var textValue = textarea.value.toLowerCase();
  if (textValue.indexOf(word) != -1) {
    document.getElementById("correcto").innerHTML = <?php echo json_encode($outputvali_of_this_page); ?>;
    return true;
      } 
        if (textValue.indexOf(word2) != -1) {
    document.getElementById("correcto").innerHTML = <?php echo json_encode($outputvali_of_this_page); ?>;
    return true;

        }  else {
    document.getElementById("incorrecto").innerHTML = 'Incorrect!  The term is not recognized as the name of a cmdlet, function, script file, or operable program.';
  }
}
```

Comment: this is very unclear, where do you want to have more than 1 word ?

Comment: Use [split](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/split) and use a for (var i;i<parts.length;i++) loop

Comment: Side note (probably): `var word = '<?php echo $answerbutton_of_this_page; ?>'; ` will fail entirely or corrupt the string if the output contains a `'`, a new line, or any JavaScript escape sequence as individual characters. The correct way (if you're going to use PHP to generate JavaScript at all) is `var word = <?php echo json_encode($answerbutton_of_this_page); ?>; `

Comment: @T.J.Crowder Can you please explain your choice of `json_encode` over `addslashes`?

Comment: @Nicolas: `json_encode` handles all necessary characters (including newlines); `addslashes` doesn't (but does add unnecessary backslashes before `'`). [According to the docs](http://php.net/manual/en/function.addslashes.php), for instance, it says it only handles `'`, `"`, ``\``, and the NULL byte. So newlines, backspaces, other control characters, none of those will be handled. Also, `json_encode` works well across multiple data types, not just strings.

Comment: @T.J.Crowder Thanks for the clarification ! :)

Answer (score 0):

It seems that `textArea` contains multiple occurrence of `word` what you want to search for. If so then this code may fulfill your expectation.

```
function validateform() {
var textarea = document.getElementById('textareabox');
  var word = '<?php echo $answerbutton_of_this_page; ?>'; 

  var textValue = textarea.value.toLowerCase();
  var idx = textValue.indexOf(word, 0);
   while( idx != -1 ){
        // console.log(textValue.indexOf(word, idx));
        // your stuffs here
        // 

        idx = textValue.indexOf(word, idx+1);
    }
```

}

the while block will loop to check if there is any other occurrence of `word`.